# Lightroom Export preset with numbering based on position in collection

Tags: lightroom, presets

So I have some collections where I have arranged the pictures in a specific sequence that derivates from the sequence the pictures were taken in (which means the file names will be mixed up). If I export them using the original filename as the new filename, they will show up on the harddrive in their original order (since they are ordered by name by the OS), not in the order they are in in the collection.

I'm trying to create a preset that will allow me to use a custom name along with a sequential number. So far, this is my Filename Template:

`{Custom Text}_{Sequence # (01)»}`

This works fine if I export the entire collection. In the export dialog, I can write e.g. `some_name` as the Custom Text and it will export the pictures as `some_name_01`, `some_name_02`, et c. However, if I want to export single images from the collection, it always starts the number sequence at #01. So if I select the eight image in my collection and export it, it will export not as `some_name_08`, but as `some_name_01`, creating a conflict between that image and the actual first one.

Is there a way to create a preset that allows me to use a Custom Text along with a sequential numbering that will produce consistent filenames when exporting the entire collection or any subset of it?

Comment: It doesn't help at export time, but can you rename the original files to have the proper sequence number?

Comment: @EightBitTony No, that would be hugely timeintensive and also has some other downsides. For example, I want them in their original order in the folder on my computer. Also I might want the same image in different collections and so on

Comment: Totally get the last two points, but Lightroom can automatically rename files, so not time intensive :)  However, as I said, understand the other two issues.

Comment: Just another reason why I like Canon's *DPP*. For as long as I can remember the batch renamer as well as the batch "convert and save" dialog has allowed the user to input whatever starting number the user desires.

Comment: The renamer in Lightroom allows you to pick the starting number, IIRC (not in front of it now), I'll check the exporter later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is no.

You can change the starting number when you export, but it still assumes you're exporting a contiguous sequence of images.  In your case, I get the feeling you might export the 5th, 7th and 10th to 15th images, in which case, even if you pick 5 as the starting number you'll get 5, 6, 7, ....

I don't think 'position in a collection' is available as a number (which is what you really want, not actually sequence number).

If you only ever export contiguous sets of images, but sometimes don't start at the 1st one, then you can do it, by simply going to the export template each time, and changing the starting number in the dialog to match the starting image number.

Comment: That's disappointing, but thanks :/ Guess I'll have to find another solution

Comment: Maybe have a search for plugins, see if [Jeffrey Friedl has any](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies) which do what you need?